# Will Users of Intermediate CA1 trust Users of intermediate CA2?

Tags: certificates, certificate-authority

I have my own CA(CA) and 2 intermediate(ICA1 & ICA2) CA's(generated using the root CA).

Using ICA1, generated a server cert(for server S1) and 2 user cert(for user U1 & U2).

Now, user certs is distributed to the user-U1 & U2(including chain trust ICA1 & CA) and they are able to successfully connect to S1.

Similarly using ICA2, generated a server cert(for server S2) and 2 user cert(for user U3 & U4).

Now, user certs is distributed to the user-U3 & U4(including chain trust ICA2 & CA) and they are able to successfully connect to S2.

Since the chain trust is distributed and both have same root CA.
Can User - U1, U2 connect to S2 and User - U3, U4 connect to S1 ?

If they can, I want that User U1 and U2 can't connect to S2 and User U3, U4 can't connect to S1.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand the use technology used for the use case (is it a http server with client certificate auth ?). You could probably solve your need by issuing U1 and U2 from S1 to be sure that no user not managed by the server can log in

Answer (score 0):

Granular access policies are enforced by using application (Access Control Lists, for example) and/or by using directory service (such as Active Directory).

Though, you can specify custom certificate policies in client certificates for U1, U2 and another policy for U3 and U4. Configure authentication/authorization services used by S1 and S2 services to accept only respective policies.

Answer (score 0):

You are misusing your tools. You are using a certificate for authorization, not authentication.

You could give some users one intermediate CA, and other users another intermediate CA, but they have the choice to trust anything at all, even a certificate without any CA.

So to answer your question, users having CA1 can trust CA2 if they want to. They can either ignore the "certificate chain not trusted" warning, or they can import CA2 on their trust store.